# relationship between functional derivative and simple derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, functional-calculus

Consider a function $f(x)$.

The derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is defined as 
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}.
$$

Sometimes, we define a functional dervative of $f$ with respect to $g$ as 
$$
\frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial g(x)}.
$$

I think it holds 
$$
\frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial g(x)}=f'(x)|_{x=g(x)}=f'(g(x)).
$$
Is it true??
If so, what conditions are required to hold the above relationship? 
(such as f(x) is differentiable, g(x) is at least continuous.)

Comment: Could you tell about the context of this so called functional derivative? Variational analysis or Hamilton or Lagrange functionals in theoretical mechanics (which is also variational calculus)?

Comment: Actually, I haven't studied a functional derivative at all. But, during my research, I should use the derivative with respect to a function. After shot google searching, I noticed that it is related to a functional derivative.....

Comment: Unless you give some context, it is impossible to give an answer. For example, it could be that $f$ maps functions to functions, then you can differentiate $f$ w.r.t. its argument, which is a function. And the notation $\partial f(g(x))/\partial g(x)$ makes no sense at all...

Comment: Always try to find out what a directional derivative looks like, all derivatives should conform to $F'(u)[v]=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{F(u+t·v)-F(u)}{t}$, where $u$, $u$ can be points of any vector space, also a function space.

Comment: OK, I am going to post a more specific example.